# Any way to run Tensorflow model remotely?

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I have a trained custom model for object recognition and now I want to use it in a Raspberry-Pi 3.

My problem is that this model is too heavy and when I try to run it on the R-Pi, it runs out of memory an my program breaks.

I was thinking in running it into a computer with enough memory and use it as a server to access from the R-Pi.

Could you give me some hints about this?
I am also open to try to train some lighter model.

Comment: I'm not sure if it would work but perhaps Distributed Training with TensorFlow https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distribute_strategy... Also perhaps run it on a cloud service provider AWS or GCP? or enable SSH maybe and use FileZilla and Transfer its contents to a computer and run it. I'm not to sure someone else might have a better idea on what to do. I figured I would give you some possible solutions in my head

Comment: You can do that any way you want, but one convenient option is [TensorFlow serving](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/serving). For lighter deployment models, consider [TensorFlow Lite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite).